# NEAR Protocol CompilationError

Tags: compiler-errors, nearprotocol, near

Hello Guys I got a CompilationError at Near (@ Macbook M1 Chip Terminal) I called the helloWorld function but I got that error. Does anyone have an idea why? Thanks in advance for help :)

```
near call dev-1649760447277-15731695561522 helloWorld --accountId kadirg.testnet
Scheduling a call: dev-1649760447277-15731695561522.helloWorld()
Doing account.functionCall()

Failure [dev-1649760447277-15731695561522]: Error: Cannot find contract code for account dev-1649760447277-15731695561522

type: 'CodeDoesNotExist'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking in:

[Stats Gallery - Contract](https://stats.gallery/testnet/dev-1649760447277-15731695561522/contract?t=week)

and:

[NEAR Testnet](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/accounts/dev-1649760447277-15731695561522)

This account has no contract deployed.
So this is not a "Compilation Error", maybe you didn't compiled and for sure you didn't deploy it.

You need to compile it with:

```
$ yarn build:release
$ asb
```

and then deploy with:

```
$ near dev-deploy ../build/release/simple.wasm
```

You can follow this guide:
[First contract AS](https://hackmd.io/@d3mage/prepare-for-ncd)

Comment: This was the problem and I figured that I did not deploy it :) Thanks for your help ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Can you check function name `helloWorld` is correct in index.ts file.

Comment: Yes it was correct but I did not deploy it first so this was the problem. Thanks for help ‍♂️